# Django Models and UniqueConstraint

Tags: django, django-models

That's my first project in Django and all those database modeling are new concept to me. Sorry if i'm all wrong.

I did had a previous model  that was working. A region has multiple depot, and a depot has multiple route. They are legacy table that I cannot change.

```
class Region(models.Model):
    regionnumber = models.IntegerField(db_column='RegionNumber', primary_key=True)
    engname = models.CharField(db_column='EngName', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.engname

class Depot(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    depotcode = models.CharField(db_column='DEPOTCODE', primary_key=True)
    depotname = models.CharField(db_column='DEPOTNAME', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.depotcode + " " + self.depotname

class Route(models.Model):
    reg_no = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    off_no = models.ForeignKey(Depot, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    res_route = models.CharField(db_column='res_route', max_length=9)
```

Now I got to add to this model a date to keep track of change in time (ex.: in 2020 some depot will be created or closed, same thing with route in depot).

Something like this.

```
class EvaluationDate(models.Model):
    ev_date = models.DateField(db_column='ev_date', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ev_date)

class Region(models.Model):
    regionnumber = models.IntegerField(db_column='RegionNumber', primary_key=True)
    engname = models.CharField(db_column='EngName', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.engname

class Depot(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    depotcode = models.CharField(db_column='DEPOTCODE', max_length=5, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    depotname = models.CharField(db_column='DEPOTNAME', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    eval_date = models.ForeignKey(EvaluationDate, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    def __str__(self):
        return self.depotcode + " " + self.depotname

    class Meta:
       constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['depotcode', 'eval_date'], name='depot_eval_date')
        ]

class Route(models.Model):
    reg_no = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    off_no = models.ForeignKey(Depot, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    res_route = models.CharField(db_column='res_route', max_length=9)  
    evaluation_date = models.ForeignKey(EvaluationDate, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Does that make sense. Is that the good way of doing things?

Now when I migrate my table "route" got the following fields added:

- evaluation_date_id as a DATE
- **off_no_id as an INT**
- reg_no_id as an INT

But "off_no_id" should be a STRING and not an Integer (legacy data) (ex.: off_no = "A001"). Is that because i remove the primary key in depot and now the migrations is confused?

I did also try to add "related_name" to my model "route" to resolve this but i'm not sure if it's the way to go.

```
class Route(models.Model):
    reg_no = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    off_no = models.ForeignKey(Depot, related_name='depotcode', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,)
    res_route = models.CharField(db_column='res_route', max_length=9)  
    evaluation_date = models.ForeignKey(EvaluationDate, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Comment: when you remove your primary key Django creates default id primary key but it is not possible for Django to change your foreign keys type because they have string values

Comment: I did drop the database and erase all migrations. What else to stop django making that integer primary key?